# Synonym for the word "information"

Tags: word-choice, phrase-request, informal-language

A friend sent me an email telling me about a job opening.  I want to send him an email telling him "**thank you for the information about the job**", but I feel that the the word "information" is very broad and formal, I want something specific and casual.

What one word or phrase can I use to replace information in the **bold** sentence above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't say that the word *information* sounds formal. Though, I agree with you that it is, in some sense, broad in meaning. It's nevertheless a very basic and everyday word just like many other words in English. So, there's really nothing wrong in using it the way you're using it in your sentence. But if you do insist on sounding a little bit more terse and casual, consider substituting the whole thing with *find*:

> Thank you for your **find**.
>
> Thanks for the **find**.

Possibly, a word like *tidbit* would work even better:

> Thanks for the **tidbit**.

Answer (score 6):

If this is a useful piece of information about the job offer then "**tip**" could be helpful:

- Thank you for the tip.

Instead of the word "**information**" you can say "**info**" which will sound less formal.

- Thanks for the info.

If it's a reference to a webpage or maybe some other source then the word "**link**" will be the right one.

- Thank you for the link.

Comment: "Tip" is a good word here (+1). It doesn't have to be confidential though - just a useful piece of information.

Comment: You may add "Thank you for the heads up", I guess. It makes no sense for me to write a new answer just for this. +1

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what exactly you want to say.

As Cookie Monster mentions, **Thank you for your find** works well.

Also:

> **Thank you for the listing.**
>
> **Thank you for the lead.**

Comment: I second the suggestion of **lead**.  In this context [in means](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/lead?s=t) "a suggestion or piece of information that helps to direct or guide," so it has the advantage of being both more casual and more precise than "information."

Answer (score 2):

You may want to thank him for contacting you rather than for the information -- that is, the communication is more important than the data. So you can choose from many synonyms for the communication itself and the act of communicating: 
contact, notice, notification, note, message, email, reaching out, letting me know, telling me, and so on.

For example:

> Thank you for letting me know about the job.

or

> Thank you for your message about the job

Answer (score 2):

You can even use word *particulars* (that is, the details). The sentence could be structured as:

> "Thank you for the particulars."

According to Dictionary.com (definition 11), the word means:

> **[particular](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/particulars)** (noun) usually **particulars**. specific points, details, or circumstances : *to give an investigator the particulars of a case*.

Answer (score 0):

You can always look up the word in a good [**thesaurus**](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/information).

My recommendations, though not a native speaker, are

> info
>   tip
>   notice
>   guidance
>   news
>   update

guessing from the context.